# How do you set colors using either rgb or hex representation using the very popular colors module?

Tags: node.js, colors

How do you set colors using either rgb or hex representation using the very popular **colors module**?
https://npmjs.org/package/colors

I read ove documentation and don't see an option, however, it seems like such a popular module would give you this control, no?

```
var colors = require('colors');

colors.setTheme({
  my_green: '#5A9664', // doesn't work
  output: 'green',
});

    console.log("A string that wants to be a color.".my_green);
```

**update, putting one of my comments in question so it's not burried:**
The colors module supports Browser mode, which clearly opens up the door for #hex colors within the html tags. The setTheme doesn't support an ANSI input array, and only takes the first half. (The module would have to be smarter to wrap the string in ansi.)

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The color format of the console cant accept these HEX color value: `#XXXXXX` you need to check these file:
https://github.com/Marak/colors.js/blob/master/colors.js and pass a [ANSI color format value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#Colors).

As the developer describes:

```
'bold'      : ['\x1B[1m',  '\x1B[22m'],
'italic'    : ['\x1B[3m',  '\x1B[23m'],
'underline' : ['\x1B[4m',  '\x1B[24m'],
'inverse'   : ['\x1B[7m',  '\x1B[27m'],
'strikethrough' : ['\x1B[9m',  '\x1B[29m'],
//grayscale
'white'     : ['\x1B[37m', '\x1B[39m'],
'grey'      : ['\x1B[90m', '\x1B[39m'],
'black'     : ['\x1B[30m', '\x1B[39m'],
//colors
'blue'      : ['\x1B[34m', '\x1B[39m'],
'cyan'      : ['\x1B[36m', '\x1B[39m'],
'green'     : ['\x1B[32m', '\x1B[39m'],
'magenta'   : ['\x1B[35m', '\x1B[39m'],
'red'       : ['\x1B[31m', '\x1B[39m'],
'yellow'    : ['\x1B[33m', '\x1B[39m']
```

Comment: Cool. Thanks. Yeh, so, there is no nice API for this then, even though `colors` module supports Browser mode, which clearly opens up the door for #hex colors within the html tags. The `setTheme` doesn't support an ANSI input array. (Well it accepts the first half but not the close, so __everything__ gets changed to that style or color.) https://github.com/Marak/colors.js/blob/master/colors.js#L192

Comment: Here is an example of the ANSI code being added to `setTheme` but not being able close it. `my_underline: ['\x1B[4m'`

Answer (score 1):

You can only override the existing theme properties and set pre-defined colors to specific keys

From the readme:

```
colors.setTheme({
  silly: 'rainbow',
  input: 'grey',
  verbose: 'cyan',
  prompt: 'grey',
  info: 'green',
  data: 'grey',
  help: 'cyan',
  warn: 'yellow',
  debug: 'blue',
  error: 'red'
});
```

For example you can set `prompt` to `green` but you cannot set `prompt` to a custom hex color

Comment: Thanks. I got that. It's a nice feature to change the name of the keys. I just want more control of the colors in the dictionary. ;D

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use hex colors in console! This example was done in Node on OSX.

```
let hex = 'AA4296'; // magenta-ish

let red = parseInt(hex.substr(0, 2), 16);
let green = parseInt(hex.substr(2, 2), 16);
let blue = parseInt(hex.substr(4,2), 16);

let fgColorString = `\x1b[38;2;${red};${green};${blue}m`;
let bgColorString = `\x1b[48;2;${red};${green};${blue}m`;
let resetFormatString = `\x1b[0m`;

console.log(`${fgColorString}Magenta Foreground`);
console.log(`${resetFormatString}Back to Normal Colors`);
console.log(`${bgColorString}Magenta Background`);
console.log(`${resetFormatString}Back to Normal Again`);
```