# How to color lines output through node.js to terminal?

Tags: logging, colors, terminal, console, cmd

When running things like `npm`, some of the logs in cmd / terminal appear in various colors.

How is this achieved?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like my answer is here:

https://github.com/marak/colors.js/

Answer (score 0):

In general you print a ASCII escape code ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code ) such as \x1B[32m (start green color) along with the rest of your message.

See a previous answer here:
[How do you set colors using either rgb or hex representation using the very popular colors module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16445790/how-do-you-set-colors-using-either-rgb-or-hex-representation-using-the-very-popu)